# Is there a way to interact with controller and scope directly in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have defined a controller and there are some variables in the scope.  May I know if there is way for me to assign a value to a variable of scope directly outside the controller (not by `ng-model`)?  Also, can I call the function of controller directly somewhere in the `<script>` element of the web page (instead of using `ng-click`)?

Thanks!

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A controller definition in angular is actually a Class and not an Object. Each place in the HTML that controller is referenced, during the compilation phase, angular creates a new controller object using the defined controller class. So, you could refer to more than one scope with the same controller class.

There is always a scope associated with a controller and all the variables are bound to that scope. You could access the scope of a particular html element by calling something like

```
var scope = angular.element("#myelement").scope();
//use the scope....
```

It would also be good if you let us know why you are trying to access the scope from outside the controller.

**UPDATE**

This is the bootstrap tab component ... You can use this as

```
<tab>
<pane title="tab1"><pane>
<pane title="tab2"></pane>
</tabs>
```

This is the same one that exists at http://angularjs.org/ main page.. I have just updated it to broadcast events when a tab changes.

```
var directives = angular.module('myApp.directives', []);
directives.directive('tabs', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        transclude:true,
        scope:{},
        controller:function ($scope, $element, $rootScope) {
            var panes = $scope.panes = [];

            $scope.select = function (pane) {
                angular.forEach(panes, function (pane) {
                    pane.selected = false;
                });
                pane.selected = true;
                $rootScope.$broadcast("tabChanged", pane.title);
            }

            this.addPane = function (pane) {
                if (panes.length == 0) $scope.select(pane);
                panes.push(pane);
            }
        },
        template:'<div class="tabbable">' +
            '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
            '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">' +
            '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
            '</li>' +
            '</ul>' +
            '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
            '</div>',
        replace:true
    };
});
directives.directive('pane', function () {
    return {
        require:'^tabs',
        restrict:'E',
        transclude:true,
        scope:{ title:'bind' },
        link:function (scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
            tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
        },
        template:'<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
            '</div>',
        replace:true
    };
});
```

This dispatches an event when the tab changes..

Comment: Basically I want to use angularjs and bootstrap (tab JavaScript component) at the same time. I have implemented REST architecture and want to retrieve resources whenever users switch to a different tab pane. So I need to bind to the tab change event and call the controller's function to retrieve from thise restful web service. Also when retrieving from the restful web service, I need to specify a user Id .. Although I fixed the user Id at first but don't want to hardcore the Id in the controller or scope in js file.

Comment: So I need to set variable (user Id) in the scope and call controller's function (retrieve data from restful web service) from outside. Any idea how this can be accomplished? Thanks!

Comment: If it is possible, i would like to avoid using custom directive as seems that not all browsers support custom directive.  But thanks for your idea.

Comment: You could use a component that is not an "element" component? Maybe as an attribute? Would that be supported by your target browsers?

Comment: hmm... have to check for that ... but thanks for all your suggestions.